# Rails: complicated routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Say I have a standard Rails application with five models: `Topic`, `Post`, `Author`, `Comment`, and `CommentAuthor`. I want `Posts` available like `domain.com/:author_name/32` and I want `Topics` available like `domain.com/12`.

It's like I want one model available under root without disrupting the others' natural hierarchy. Is that even possible in Rails?

**UPDATE**

It's because I keep getting errors like this when loading resources:

```
{"controller"=>"topic", "action"=>"show", "post"=>"assets", "id"=>"social-icons", "format"=>"css"}
```

Comment: Yep! http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Topics, assuming that your controller is Topics Controller

```
get '/:id', to: 'topics#show'
```

For the Posts, it would be

```
get '/:author_name/:id', to: 'posts#show'
```

Also, please have a read through the guides:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: is author_name not a parameter?

Comment: Yeah, I meant `author_name` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want a nested route, with

```
 resources :authors do 
  resources :posts
 end
```

Assuming you did your model associations properly that would be the start of your routing. to get domain.com/author_name/32, you'll need to customise it a little. Perhaps

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

can help you out.